# bash-like message about non-installed command in zsh

Tags: zsh

For example, I don't have command `nethogs` installed.

If I type `nethogs` in `bash` I get this message:

```
Command «nethogs» not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nethogs
```

But if I type `nethogs` in `zsh` I get this:

```
zsh: command not found: nethogs
```

How can I make `zsh` to search unknown command in repositories and suggest me to install it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://superuser.com/questions/1580312/command-not-found-but-can-be-installed-with-prompt-in-linux-mint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append plugin `command-not-found` into `~/.zshrc` file like that:

```
plugins=(... command-not-found)
```

If you don't have `command-not-found` installed, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install command-not-found
```